# Scroll to next anchor after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a website and I want to build some window-sized divs/sections. When the user **stops scrolling between** two of these divs, the **div which takes more space in that moment should be scrolled at**, so it's gonna be full-window-sized.

Comment: It seems you are loooking for [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) but keeping the scrolling bar? Check out [this demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html) or [this other one](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are jQuery plugins to do this but here's a good template to see how you can implement your own:

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/

Here's the relevant scrolling JavaScript for easing function to make it nice and scrollable:

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[FullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) does exactly what you need.

If the whole library is too heavy for what you need, you could try to reimplement the logic with something like this https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/pure%20javascript%20(Alpha)/javascript.fullPage.js#L897-L913